# Custom pipes in Aspose.Words for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I'm using Aspose.Words for .NET and they have built-in pipes to process words, for example

```
:upper - converts a string to upper case
:caps - capitalizes a first letter
```

I'm wondering is there a way when I can write my own pipes?

Comment: I see that you have already posted this query in [Aspose.Words forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) below:
[Custom pipes in Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/817615/custom-pipes-in-aspose.words-for-.net.aspx).

We need to understand and test this scenario on our end; please post your documents and code in your thread in Aspose.Words forum for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Just answered - https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/818175/custom-pipes-in-aspose.words-for-.net/showthread.aspx#818175, please check my reply